# How can I run some code when a Django model’s save method is called for the first time?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I could have sworn I’d read a question about this before, but I can’t find it, so:

In Django, how can I run some code when a new model instance is saved to the database?

I know I can write a custom `MyModel().save()` method to run some code whenever a model instance is saved. But how can I run code only when a model instance is saved for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django documentation was hard for me to grok at first, here's a more explicit example

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from yourapp.models import YourModel

def model_created(sender, **kwargs):
    the_instance = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:
        do_some_stuff(the_instance)

post_save.connect(model_created, sender=YourModel)
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I've never liked signals very much (spooky action at a distance). Also - it's peculiar to have two very different ways to do this - overriding save() on hand and a signal on the other.

Comment: There's a missing ":" in the model_created definition

Answer (score 4):

Ah yes: [the `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/signals/#post-save) passes an argument called `created`, which is `True` if its instance was created by the call to `save()`.

Comment: You can also check if self.pk exists in the save method - often the choice I'd make depending on complexity. Setting a timestamp before auto_now_add existed for example :)