# run some python function whenever a model is created or updated in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I want to run some code after my `model` is saved. Three places to do this will be

1) override save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
        do_something()
```

2) use post_save signal:

```
def model_created(sender, **kwargs)
    the_instance = kwargs['instance']
    if kwargs['created']:
        do_something()

post_save.connect(model_created, sender=YourModel)
```

3) do this in the view itself.

```
if form.is_valid():
   do_something()
   return redirect(reverse("homepage"))
```

All three should work. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916741/run-some-code-when-a-models-save-method-is-called-for-the-first-time) advocates the second one.

My question is that the second method (`post_save`) works when the model is first created. I want to call `do_something()` whenever a new model is created and also when an existing model is updated.
In the latter case, I will have `kwargs[`created`]` to be `false`. how do I handle this situation?

P.S: I am currently doing the third one which works fine for both `updateView` and `CreateView`.
but the problem is it takes time to return from the `do_something() function` before it is being redirected.

Comment: Why don't omit `if kwargs['created']` check in the `post_save` signal handler?

Comment: I want it to handle when both model is created or when it is updated. without the check, the first is not recommended

Comment: Remove the `if kwargs['created']` check and `do_something()` would be called whenever model is created or updated.

Comment: yes, I understand what you mean. but I guess it is a not a good practice to call something before checking it is created..

Comment: *the problem is it takes time to return from the do_something() function before it is being redirected* The exact same time will be taken in all three cases. Signals in Django are not asynchronous.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry: yes, you are correct. As pointed out, I should use celery or some multiprocessing module?

Comment: That's probably the way to go. There are packages that allow you to use the signals API while specifying that something should execute asynchronously on celery (for example [async-signals](https://github.com/nyergler/async-signals), though I haven't used it personally).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal is the cleanest option among these three.

Just eliminate `if kwargs['created']` and call `do_something()` right in the body of a function:

```
def model_created_or_updated(sender, **kwargs):
    the_instance = kwargs['instance']
    do_something()

post_save.connect(model_created_or_updated, sender=YourModel)
```

Now, every time `YourModel` is created or updated `do_something()` would be called.

FYI, `created` is just a flag that indicates whether `YourModel` was created (value is `True`) or updated (value is `False`).

Note that `do_something()` will be executed synchronously and will be "blocking" until done. If you want to execute `do_something` asynchronously, you need to go with a real task management tool, like [`celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/) package.